# Is it possible disable or enable a column in a table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table name `Products` and column `image` in it that I don't want to use for now, but I don't want to use it accidentally too. If we disable it and use it in our query, I want it to say that the column doesn't exist, and when enable it and we can perform queries on it.

Comment: You can use a view

Answer (score 1):

MySql has column-based permissions, so you can `REVOKE` access to that table and then `GRANT` access back for only the columns you want:

```
GRANT SELECT (field1, field2, field3) ON Products TO 'user'@'host';
```

(And so on, for `INSERT`, `DELETE`, whatever.)

This wouldn't require any change to your source code or schema. See [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html) for details.